# Intragram Client ID issue

Tags: api, instagram

I'm having serious trouble with Instagram and getting the latest posts to feed a JSON result.

I'm using the following link:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/CLIENT_ID/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN#

I've registered an app on Instagram, and put the Client ID on the app and put it into the link above.  I've registered the client id to get an access token but it's still doing the same thing.

The link says page not found but it seems to be the right link.

Any ideas? Does it take a while to register a client id for it to become valid?

My Client ID is a mix of letters and numbers, is that right?

On another note, what's the Client Secret for?

Answer (score 1):

The ID in the recent media feed is the user ID of the user whose photos you wish to view (which would be a number), not the client ID of your application.  That should only be used to get the access token via the oauth process.

If you don't know the user id you can find it by using the ../v1/users/search end point.

The Client Secret is used as part of that oauth process to get a valid access token.